# Perl list of array references

Tags: arrays, perl, list, dereference

I have a list of array references:
`my @a = ([1,2],[3,4])`
How can I get an array called "@b" with the first array in @a (`(1,2)`)?  I've tried various combinations of dereferencing but they all seem to throw errors.

Comment: Thanks, @b = @{$a[0]}; worked!  But I'm confused.  Why is it necessary to use the curly braces to do this dereferencing?  The documentation I've seen says that you should be able to put a '@' directly before an array reference, like @myArr=@$myArrRef.  I tried doing things like $temp=$a[0]; @b=@$temp, or @b=@($a[0]), but none of them worked.  Why are curly braces needed just because I made an array of references?

Answer (score 6):

Dereference first element from `@a` array,

```
my @b = @{ $a[0] };
```

note that `@b` array is a copy, and eventual changes will not reflect on `@{$a[0]}`

Answer (score 2):

`@a` actually contains two elements above - both references to sub arrays. It might look like 4 elements, but it isn't.

So you could do:

```
my ( $ref1, $ref2 ) = @a;
```

And then dereference `$ref1`:

```
@b = @{ $ref1 };
```

But as I'm sure you'll have spotted - you don't need to call it `$ref1` because it's *also* `$a[0]`. Hence:

```
@b = @{$a[0]};
```

Note - you need the braces - `@$a[0]` is actually `(@$a)[0]` which isn't what you want. ( as `$a` is undefined)